# Activate combo-box action on select value using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am displaying a combo-box which contains all sheet names of the workbook.
If i select a value, i want Excel to jump to the selected sheet.

I tried doing an activate code line on this code, but it does not seem to work.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim sVal As String

With ComboBox1
sVal = .Text
.Clear
For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If Sh.Name <> "Inputs" Then
.AddItem Sh.Name
End If
Next
.Value = sVal
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the sheet names in the `Change Event`? That will **re-fire** the Change Event. I would recommend populating that, say in the `UserForm_Initialize` event.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim Sh As Worksheet

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Sh.Name <> "Inputs" Then
            ComboBox1.AddItem Sh.Name
        End If
    Next

    ComboBox1.Style = fmStyleDropDownList
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ComboBox1.Text)
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

**My Assumption**

You have this Combobox on a Userform. If not, then make relevant changes to the code. But the gist remains the same.

**Followup From Comments**

Add a button on the worksheet. Name it say `Refresh` and use this code

```
Dim Sh As Worksheet

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ComboBox1.Clear

    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Sh.Name <> "Inputs" Then
            ComboBox1.AddItem Sh.Name
        End If
    Next

    ComboBox1.Style = fmStyleDropDownList
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ComboBox1.Text)
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope it is on the worksheet itself . No userform involved!

Comment: Then Instead of `UserForm_Initialize`, Use `Workbook_Open` Event

Comment: It works perfectly but everytime i run it again, the sheetnames repeat itself. For example i have sheets 1 to 4 but it has at least 3 sheet1s in the drop downlist since i ran it thrice. Any ways to stop this?

Comment: Add `Comboxo1.Clear` (But do not add it in the Change Event)

Comment: Now the combo box is blank.

Comment: You need to close and reopen the workbook for it to work. Alternatively, you can put a button on the sheet. Rename the button to `Refresh` and put the code which poupulates the combobox in that.

Comment: Thanks alot for taking the trouble! It works just fine now:)